# retrieve first_name and last_name from auth hash using omniauth-google-oauth2 gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, omniauth

I have a rails 4.2.7 app setup using the `omniauth-google-oauth2` gem, and I would like to retrieve the `first_name` and `last_name` from the auth hash.

I was able to do this with the `omniauth-facebook` gem by modifying the `devise.rb` to look like the following,

**devise.rb**

```
# Omniauth / Oauth2 settings
  callback_url = if Rails.env == "development"
   ENV['FB_CALLBACK']
  else
    ENV['FB_CALLBACK_PROD']
  end

  config.omniauth :facebook, ENV['FACEBOOK_KEY'], ENV['FACEBOOK_SECRET'], callback_url: callback_url,
   :scope => 'email',
   :info_fields => 'email, first_name, last_name'
  # Google - OmniAuth
  require 'omniauth-google-oauth2'
  config.omniauth :google_oauth2, ENV["GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID"], ENV["GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET"]
```

However, I can't seem to figure out how to retrieve the first_name / last_name using `omniauth-google-oauth2`.  Any help would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: What all you are showing is the configuration. Now the response is available [here](https://github.com/zquestz/omniauth-google-oauth2#devise) when u call `User.from_omniauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"]` method.

Answer (score 0):

@chris from omniauth-google-oauth2, in your callback controller action,

`auth = request.env['omniauth.auth']`

`request.env['omniauth.auth']` will contain a hash of users' auth session, with which basic user info are persisted in `info` i.e. `auth["info"]`

```
auth
====
{
.....
"info"=>
  {"name"=>"Username",
   "email"=>"Useremail",
   "first_name"=>"firstname",
   "last_name"=>"lastname",
   "image"=> "image_url",
   "urls"=>{"Google"=>"https://plus.google.com/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}
  }
....
}
```